# Merge two string with new line

Tags: java, string, merge, newline

At the moment, I have two string

```
 String str1="In the morning
              I have breakfast
              After";

 String str2="In the afternoon
              I have dinner
              Before";
```

I want to merge two string to create a string as follow:

```
String strMerge="In the morning
                 In the afternoon
                 I have breakfast
                 I have dinner
                 After
                 Before"
```

How must I do?

Comment: `strMerge= str1+str2`?? Please be clear on what basis you need to merge.

Comment: ARe there any rules for your merge?

Comment: Your example is invalid Java.  String literals must be terminated before the end of the line on which they start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you use `\n` for new line, (if no, set split as: `str1.split("[ ]+")`):

```
String str1 = "In the morning\r\n" + 
                "              I have breakfast\r\n" + 
                "              After";

        String str2 = "In the afternoon\r\n" + 
                "              I have dinner\r\n" + 
                "              Before";         

        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();           

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str1.split("\r\n")));
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str2.split("\r\n")));

        if(list1.size() == list2.size()){           
            for(int i = 0; i<list1.size(); i++){
                buff.append(list1.get(i)).append("\r\n")
                    .append(list2.get(i)).append("\r\n");
            }           
        }

        System.out.print(buff.toString());
```

Output:

```
In the morning
In the afternoon
              I have breakfast
              I have dinner
              After
              Before
```